# How to give dataframe inside isin()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask, dask-dataframe

I want convert a sql query like

```
SELECT * FROM df WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM an_df)
```

into dask equivalent.
So, I am trying this:

```
d=df[df['id'].isin(an_df['id'])]
```

But it is thorwing *NotImplementedError: passing a 'dask.datframe.core.DataFrame' to'isin'*

Then I converted this an_df['id'] to list like

```
d=df[df['id'].isin(list(an_df['id']))] or d=df[df['id'].isin(an_df['id'].compute())]
```

but this is very time consuming.

I want a solution that works as fast as dask.
df has approximately 100 million rows.

Please help me with it.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I recommend adding a minimal reproducible example, which will make solving this particular issue easier:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

It seems like you are converting the `pandas.core.series.Series` object returned by `an_df['id'].compute()` to a `list`, which is not needed. `isin()` will take a pandas series or dataframe object as argument. Please see:

https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.isin.html

In your example this should work:

```
series_to_match = an_df['id'].compute() 

d=df[df['id'].isin(series_to_match)]
```

So you can omit the `.to_list()` cast. I expect this to be a little bit faster since that type casting can be dropped. But there are still things you need to consider here. Depending on the size of `an_df['id'].compute()` you may run into trouble since that statement is pulling the resulting `series` object into the memory of the machine your scheduler is running on.

if this series is small enough you could try to use a `client.scatter` to make sure all of your workers have that series persisted in memory, see:

http://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/locality.html

If that `series` is a huge object you'll have to tackle this differently.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @matthiasdv. So, my dataframe is huge (approx 100 million of rows) so I cannot go ahead with client.scatter. And the first solution you gave (compute()), it works but I cannot use it because it is very slow and affects the performance.

Comment: just taking a step back here - you're looking for a many-to-many filtering operation, by which I mean, filtering partitioned, remote data based on a conditioning value which is itself a partitioned, remote series. This is always going to be hard and slow. Check out the dask docs on [understanding performance](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/understanding-performance.html) and [best practices](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe-best-practices.html). SQL will be faster - this type of operation is what that language was written for. But this is the correct answer for dask.